# Python class methods, when to return self?

Tags: python, oop

I'm confused as to when to return self inside a class and when to return a value which may or may not possibly be used to check the method ran correctly.

```
def api_request(self, data):
    #api web request code
    return response.text
def connect(self):
    #login to api, set some vars defined in __init__
    return self
def send_message(self, message):
    #send msg code
    return self
```

So above theres a few examples. api_request I know having the text response is a must. But with send_message what should I return?

which is then converted to a dict to check a key exists, else raise error).

Should it return True, the response->dict, or self?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Since errors tend to be delivered as exceptions and hence success/fail return values are rarely useful, a lot of object-modifier functions wind up with no return value at all—or more precisely, return `None`, since you can't return nothing-at-all.  (Consider some of Python's built-in objects, like `list`, where `append` and `extend` return `None`, and `dict`, where `dict.update` returns `None`.)

Still, returning `self` is convenient for chaining method calls, even if some Pythonistas don't like it.  See kindall's answer in [Should internal class methods returnvalues or just modify instance variables in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017364/should-internal-class-methods-returnvalues-or-just-modify-instance-variables-in?rq=1) for example.

---

Edit to add some examples based on comment:

What you "should" return—or raise an exception, in which case, "what exception"—depends on the problem.  Do you want `send_message()` to wait for a response, validate that response, and verify that it was good?  If so, do you want it to raise an error if there is no response, the validation fails, or the response was valid but says "message rejected"?  If so, do you want *different* errors for each failure, etc?  One reasonable (for some value of reasonable) method is to capture all failures with a "base" exception, and make each "type" of failure a derivative of that:

```
class ZorgError(Exception):      # catch-all "can't talk via the Zorg-brand XML API"
    pass

class ZorgRemoteDown(ZorgError): # connect or send failed, or no response/timeout
    pass

class ZorgNuts(ZorgError):       # remote response incomprehensible
    pass

class ZorgDenied(ZorgError):     # remote says "permission denied"
    pass

# add more if needed
```

Now some of your functions might look something like this (note, none of this is tested):

```
def connect(self):
    """connect to server, log in"""
    ... # do some prep work
    addr = self._addr
    try:
        self._sock.connect(addr)
    except socket.error as err:
        if err.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED: # server is down
            raise ZorgRemoteDown(addr)      # translate that to our Zorg error
        # add more special translation here if needed
        raise                               # some other problem, propagate it
    ... # do other stuff now that we're connected, including trying to log in
    response = self._get_response()
    if response == 'login denied'   # or whatever that looks like
        raise ZorgDenied()          # maybe say what exactly was denied, maybe not
    # all went well, return None by not returning anything

def send_message(self, msg):
    """encode the message in the way the remote likes, send it, and wait for
    a response from the remote."""
    response = self._send_and_wait(self._encode(msg))
    if response == 'ok':
        return
    if response == 'permission denied':
        raise ZorgDenied()
    # don't understand what we got back, so say the remote is crazy
    raise ZorgNuts(response)
```

Then you need some "internal" functions like these:

```
def _send_and_wait(self, raw_xml):
    """send raw XML to server"""
    try:
        self._sock.sendall(raw_xml)
    except socket.error as err:
        if err.errno in (errno.EHOSTDOWN, errno.ENETDOWN) # add more if needed
            raise ZorgRemoteDown(self._addr)
        raise
    return self._get_response()

def _get_response(self):
    """wait for a response, which is supposedly XML-encoded"""
    ... some code here ...
    if we_got_a_timeout_while_waiting:
       raise ZorgRemoteDown(self._addr)
    try:
        return some_xml_decoding_stuff(raw_xml)
    except SomeXMLDecodeError:
        raise ZorgNuts(raw_xml) # or something else suitable for debug
```

You might choose not to translate `socket.error`s at all, and not have all your own errors; perhaps you can squeeze your errors into `ValueError` and `KeyError` and so on, for instance.

These choices are what programming is all about!

Comment: I understand if my method is get_list_of_something() i should return [] on failure. But looking at the above xml example, what would i return there? Bool?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, objects in python are mutable.  You therefore do not return `self`, as the modifications you make in a method are reflected in the object itself.

To use your example:

```
api = API() # initialise the API
if api.connect(): # perhaps return a bool, indicating that the connection succeeded
    api.send_message() # you now know that this API instance is connected, and can send messages
```

Comment: connect() has within it a try/exception (exception if the login fails) and is never executed by the user really, should it still return bool in this case? Or nothing?

Comment: If to return nothing, method behind of scenes return `None`

Comment: @AbbasovAlexander I know that, but if the method return value is never checked anywhere, should nothing be returned. (best practise wise). And if the method does need to return something (to show if it was successful), should it be bool, or something else like a response id?

Comment: It depending from the task. You can return bool, object or tuple that included any data. For `api.connect()` probably better to use instance connect.