# Returning "self"? what does it really do and when do we need to return self

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

I encountered a code which looks similar to this:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager, ContextDecorator

class makepara(ContextDecorator):
     def __enter__(self):
        print ("<p>")
        return self

     def __exit__(self, *args):
         print ("</p>")
         return False

@makepara()
def emit_data():
    print (" here is HTML code")

    emit_data()
```

I found related answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459970/python-class-methods-when-to-return-self.)
but when i change the above code to

```
from contextlib import contextmanager, ContextDecorator

class makepara(ContextDecorator):
    def __enter__(self):
        print ("<p>")

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print ("</p>")

@makepara()
def emit_data():
    print (" here is HTML code")

emit_data()
```

there is no change in the output, that makes me wonder what does `return self` actually does and how to be used?

Comment: *Note:* the `return False` from `__exit__` is entirely useless and can be removed.  Conditionally returning truthy values, however, can be used for suppressing exceptions from the context block.

Answer (score 4):

You choose to return `self` (or some other object, but usually the context manager instance it`self`) so that a name can be bound with this syntax:

```
with makepara() as var:
    ...
```

The object returned by `__enter__` will be bound to the name `var` within the context (and will, in fact, remain bound to `var` after exiting context).

If you wouldn't need any value bound after entering context, it  is possible to omit an explicit return (the implicit return of `None` would be used in this case regardless) but there is no harm and no disadvantage in returning `self` anyway.

Comment: In other words, there's no reason to return anything because the `with` statement is outside of your control anyway? (It's being called by `ContextDecorator`)

Comment: Maybe not in this case, but inheriting `ContextDecorator` simply gives you the code allowing to use your context manager as a decorator, for free.  It remains perfectly valid to use it in a `with` statement as well.

Comment: So its more like a good coding practice as returning self is not serving any purpose:  is that it?

Comment: In your html example it doesn't seem particularly useful.  But in many (most?) other use-cases, we actually want to interact with the context manager instance from within the context block. So, usually, it is serving a useful purpose.

Answer (score 2):

`return self` is not only useful in `with` statement, but also useful in many other situations.

For example, when you open a file using:

```
with open("file") as f:
    ....
```

Function `open` actually return an object which implements `__enter__`, and in its `__enter__`, it use `return self` to let you bind this instance to variable `f`, so that you can do `f.read` or something else after.

In other situations, for another example, if you want to chained call(Maybe `data = a.connect().get("key").to_dict()`). You need to add `return self` to `connect` and `get`.

But after all, `return self` is nothing more than returning a normal variable.