# How to override the insert functionality of a list to return the list

Tags: python

In python, lists have an insert method, which returns None.

```
li = ['a','b']
print li.insert(1,'a')
None
```

I need it to return the list,

```
print li.insert(1,'a')
['a','a','b']
```

I am trying to do it by creating a new class, but I am stuck

```
class Nlist(list):
    def insert(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(Nlist,self).insert(*args,**kwargs)
        return #what?
```

Comment: I feel like I might be missing something but is there a reason you can't just print the new list with `print li`? If there is a reason this is insufficient then you should edit the question and explain why and explain the use case involved.

Comment: @shuttle87 I can, but I am trying to do this simple override so that I don't have to use an extra variable for a temporary assignment.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, lists are mutable so you have to have modified a preexisting list when using `insert`. How does an extra variable for temporary assignment come into this?

Comment: @shuttle87 it might be stupid, but I have a string, which doesn't have an insert method, so i convert it to a list, apply insert, then use join to reconvert it to a string, all in a list comprehension where there are several strings iterated over. I'll think of a better way, but right now this solves my problem.

Comment: insert just doesn't return anything - it changes the list inplace so do the insert then print the list

Comment: @yayu What you've just described is an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Ask about your initial problem, not about the workaround you've come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass list like this:

```
class Nlist(list):
    def insert(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Nlist, self).insert(*args, **kwargs)
        return self
```

Comment: (But, don't do this...)

Comment: Well, it's not very "pythonic" -- but it's not without some controversy (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017364/should-internal-class-methods-returnvalues-or-just-modify-instance-variables-in, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459970/python-class-methods-when-to-return-self, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29657/purpose-of-return-self-from-a-class-method)

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
    li = ['a','b']
    print li.insert(1,'a')
    None
```

do this

```
    li = ['a','b']
    li.insert(1,'a')
    print li
    ['a','a','b']
```